# the cross ratio with two $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

The cross ratio of four complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4$ (with at least three being distinct) is 
$$\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)}.$$
Once $z_1$ is $\infty$, we can define the cross ratio by taking limits as
$$(\infty,z_2,z_3,z_4)=\frac{z_2-z_4}{z_2-z_3}.$$
However, when $z_1=z_2=\infty$, what the cross ratio means?

I need this to construct a Mobius transform $w(z)$ so that it takes $-1,1,i$ to $\infty,\infty,i$.

Comment: There is none - Möbius transformations are bijective.

Answer (score 4):

Möbius transformations are one to one on the Riemann sphere, so there is no hope of finding your $w$.

Answer (score 2):

As mrf said, it's not possible to find such a Möbius transformation, since they are invertible.

However, if you just want to find a rational function, it's not too bad.  Call this function $f$.  Since $f$ takes $\pm 1$ to $\infty$, then its denominator must be $(z-1)(z+1) = z^2 - 1$.  We see that $\frac{1}{i^2 - 1} = -\frac{1}{2}$, so
$$
f(z) = \frac{-2i}{z^2 - 1}
$$
should fit the bill.